# Edit table content and save it to database

Tags: android, html

I have a HTML table that is editable. I already used `contenteditable` but after that I just have no idea how to save the changes. It only saves while I am on that page but after I reload it sets page to initial value. The table is project for school. Simple solution is much appreciated since I don't know much about android app development. Here is my code:

```
<head> 
    <style> 
        th{
            background-color:lightblue;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:20p‌​t
        } 
        .open{
            color:black;
            background-color:lightblue;
            font-size:15pt
        } 
        .chapel{
            color:blue;
            background-color:lightblue;
            font-size:10pt‌​
        }
     </style> 
</head>
<body> 
    <table border=7 width=10%>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align=center rowspan=2 class="open"><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="example-one" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What database software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery("#savebtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_url_address',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            information :   jQuery('#content').html(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response){
              //  jQuery('#UserCityId').html(response.content);
                alert('save successfull');

            }else{
                alert('not save');
            }
        }
     });

  });
});
```

user ajax to post all content from DIV and save

```
<div id="content">
  <table> {table content heare}</table>
</div>
```